# Disabling sandbox from CSP in Servlet

Tags: servlets, content-security-policy, servlet-filters

I am working on a Servlet application, which generates a page with an embedded iframe. I need the iframe to not have the sandbox attribute. But somewhere in the application the CSP for iframe is getting set with the sandbox attribute.
I want to know where and how at the server end I can remove sandbox attribute from CSP for an iframe.
Any help is greatly appreciated.